# How do I set global options with Apex chart?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Say I want some options to be global for all Apex charts. For colors it can be done with:

```
Apex.colors = ['#F44336', '#E91E63', '#9C27B0'];
```

Now what if I want all charts to be `300px` high. What I try is:

```
Apex.chart.height = 300;
Apex.chart.width = '100%';
```

Because `width` and `height` are under `chart` according to their [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/height/).

However this has no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Please ignore this one, I found a solution `Apex.chart = { ... }`.

Comment: It would be great if you could post your full solution as an answer.  :) You're allowed to answer your own questions here on SO. That would help out future users.

Answer (score 2):

You already found an answer, but anyone looking for a full solution, here is how you set the global options for the `options.chart` property which applies to all the charts on that page.

```js
Apex = {
  chart: {
    background: '#fefefe',
    height: 400,
    foreColor: '#333'
  }
}
```

Note that the variable `Apex` is a global variable equivalent to `window.Apex` and available everywhere.

Comment: Window.Apex has no data while using ng-apexcharts. Please help!

Comment: I get this error when using this solution: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`. I also tried using `Object.assign(Apex, globalOptions)`.